# Verifying that these 2 parametric equations describe the same plane

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, parametric

For $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb R$ we define:

$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-4\\
\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
-5\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} \qquad (1)\quad $

and

$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-4\\
\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
-5\\
4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} \qquad (2)\quad$

I want to check if $(1),(2)$ describe the same plane. To this end, it suffices to calculate the cartesian equation for each parametric equation and see whether they coincide or not.

For $(1)$:
$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-4\\
\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
-5\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} $ which yields the system

$\begin{alignat}{3}
1&+\lambda&&-\mu &&&=x_1\\
1&\;&&-5\mu &&&=x_2\\
1&-4\lambda &&\;&&&=x_3
\end{alignat}$

Multiplying with the appropriate coefficients and taking the sum, I find that: $20x_1-4x_2+5x_3=21$

In the exact same way I obtain for $(2)$ that $20x_1-4x_2+5x_3=21$ and hence I conclude that the two equations describe the same plane.

Is this conclusion correct or did I miss something? Is there any other way to check whether two parametric equations describe the same plane?

Many thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, given that the fixed points are the same, you could calculate the cross-product of the direction vectors for each plane and see if they are parallel. Indeed they are.